# Two dependent random variables with independent functions

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, stochastic-analysis

Question:
Provide an example of two random variables
$X,Y$
and two functions
$f,g
:\mathbb{R}
\rightarrow
\mathbb{R}$
such that
$X$
and
$Y$
are
not
independent but
$f(X)$ and $
g(Y)$
are
independent. You may
not
pick
$f$
and
$g$
such that either
$f(X)$ or
$g(Y)$ is constant with probability one.

I got this question in Probablity Theory class and I've been trying to come up with an answer but everything I come up with turns out to be a constant function which is not allowed. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Rademacher random variable, i.e. $P(X = 1) = P(X = -1) = \dfrac{1}{2}$, and $N$ a non-constant positive random variable that is independent of $X$ (e.g. $N \sim U([1, 2])$). Now set $Y = XN$.

$X$ and $Y$ are clearly not independent, since
$$P(Y > 0, X > 0) = P(X > 0) = \dfrac{1}{2} \ne \dfrac{1}{4} = P(Y > 0) P(X > 0)$$
holds. But $|Y| = N$ is independent of $X$.